# Stop keyframe animation at top of div?

Tags: css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm using [this fun scrolling text effect](http://www.sitepoint.com/css3-starwars-scrolling-text/) on my 404 page, but I need the (short) text to stop and just remain visible once it reaches the top of the page instead of scrolling all the way up and away.  How do I make that happen with just CSS? I'd like to use as little js as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I butchered the codebase a bit, but basically you want to remove `infinite` [iteration count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-iteration-count) from the `slide` animations and add in its place `forward` (which is a [fill mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation-fill-mode)).  Then you want to replace the `top` values in the animations with `top: 0%`.  Lastly, you want to remove the black fade on `#titles:after` which can be done by either removing it entirely or lowering its opacity.  Still needs work, but this is the general idea (going to have to run it in "Full page" mode):

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Sans:400,700);

* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

body, html
{
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 font-family: "Droid Sans", arial, verdana, sans-serif;
 font-weight: 700;
 color: #ff6;
 background-color: #000;
 overflow: hidden;
}

p#start
{
 position: relative;
 width: 16em;
 font-size: 200%;
 font-weight: 400;
 margin: 20% auto;
 color: #4ee;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 -webkit-animation: intro 2s ease-out;
 -moz-animation: intro 2s ease-out;
 -ms-animation: intro 2s ease-out;
 -o-animation: intro 2s ease-out;
 animation: intro 2s ease-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes intro {
 0% { opacity: 1; }
 90% { opacity: 1; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes intro {
 0% { opacity: 1; }
 90% { opacity: 1; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes intro {
 0% { opacity: 1; }
 90% { opacity: 1; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes intro {
 0% { opacity: 1; }
 90% { opacity: 1; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes intro {
 0% { opacity: 1; }
 90% { opacity: 1; }
 100% { opacity: 0; }
}

h1
{
 position: absolute;
 width: 2.6em;
 left: 50%;
 top: 25%;
 font-size: 10em;
 text-align: center;
 margin-left: -1.3em;
 line-height: 0.8em;
 letter-spacing: -0.05em;
 color: #000;
 text-shadow: -2px -2px 0 #ff6, 2px -2px 0 #ff6, -2px 2px 0 #ff6, 2px 2px 0 #ff6;
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 1;
 -webkit-animation: logo 5s ease-out 2.5s;
 -moz-animation: logo 5s ease-out 2.5s;
 -ms-animation: logo 5s ease-out 2.5s;
 -o-animation: logo 5s ease-out 2.5s;
 animation: logo 5s ease-out 2.5s;
}

h1 sub
{
 display: block;
 font-size: 0.3em;
 letter-spacing: 0;
 line-height: 0.8em;
}

@-webkit-keyframes logo {
 0% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; }
 50% { opacity: 1; }
 100% { -webkit-transform: scale(0.1); opacity: 0; }
}

@-moz-keyframes logo {
 0% { -moz-transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; }
 50% { opacity: 1; }
 100% { -moz-transform: scale(0.1); opacity: 0; }
}

@-ms-keyframes logo {
 0% { -ms-transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; }
 50% { opacity: 1; }
 100% { -ms-transform: scale(0.1); opacity: 0; }
}

@-o-keyframes logo {
 0% { -o-transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; }
 50% { opacity: 1; }
 100% { -o-transform: scale(0.1); opacity: 0; }
}

@keyframes logo {
 0% { transform: scale(1); opacity: 1; }
 50% { opacity: 1; }
 100% { transform: scale(0.1); opacity: 0; }
}

/* the interesting 3D scrolling stuff */
#titles
{
 position: absolute;
 width: 18em;
 height: 10em;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -9em;
 font-size: 350%;
 text-align: justify;
 overflow: hidden;
 -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -o-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 transform-origin: 50% 100%;
 -webkit-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(25deg);
 -moz-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(25deg);
 -ms-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(25deg);
 -o-transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(25deg);
 transform: perspective(300px) rotateX(25deg);
}

#titles:after
{
 position: absolute;
 content: ' ';
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 60%;
 background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, transparent 100%);
 background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, transparent 100%);
 background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, transparent 100%);
 background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, transparent 100%);
 background-image: linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 0%, transparent 100%);
 pointer-events: none;
}

#titles p
{
 text-align: justify;
 margin: 0.8em 0;
}

#titles p.center
{
 text-align: center;
}

#titles a
{
 color: #ff6;
 text-decoration: underline;
}

#titlecontent
{
 position: absolute;
 top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
 -webkit-animation: scroll 10s linear 4s forwards;
 -moz-animation: scroll 10s linear 4s forwards;
 -ms-animation: scroll 10s linear 4s forwards;
 -o-animation: scroll 10s linear 4s forwards;
 animation: scroll 10s linear 4s forwards;
}

/* animation */
@-webkit-keyframes scroll {
 0% { top: 100%; }
 100% { top: 0% }
}

@-moz-keyframes scroll {
 0% { top: 100%; }
 100% { top: 0% }
}

@-ms-keyframes scroll {
 0% { top: 100%; }
 100% { top: 0% }
}

@-o-keyframes scroll {
 0% { top: 100%; }
 100% { top: 0% }
}

@keyframes scroll {
 0% { top: 100%; }
 100% { top: 0% }
}
```

```html
<p id="start">A short time ago in a browser very, very close&hellip;</p>

<h1>STAR WARS<sub>titles in CSS3</sub></h1>

<div id="titles"><div id="titlecontent">

 <p class="center">ERROR 404</p>
 
 <p class="center">Page not found</p>
</div></div>
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you awfully much! Now I just have to fiddle around to make it a bit more responsive.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is my CodePen for what I'm working on (still working getting BB8 animated properly):  [link](http://codepen.io/ThePixelPixie/pen/obzbbN)

Comment: @LauraSage  lol nice!  Good work on the parallaxing and animation.  Good luck on your project.